# General HTTP error: Domain name not found

Tags: google-search-console, sitemap, xml-sitemap

I have verified my domain through a TXT record by google, however, my site hasn't indexed yet and I face with sitemap errors in google webmaster tool. I run dns health check from http://dnscheck.pingdom.com/ ,and everything seems ok. But as you can see from the snapshot below webmaster gives `General HTTP error: Domain name not found` error. I will appreciate for any help and thanks anwyway.

EDIT: My site is buraktas.com

[image]

Comment: I suggest you check your site's .htaccess rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google is reaching your sitemap file okay and complaining about the domain name used within the sitemap. I looked at your sitemap, and it all looks okay at first glance. The only thing I can think of, is that you have Google Webmaster Tools domain name set to www.buraktas.com and your sitemap is using buraktas.com. Check this. You may need to change one or the other. Also, know that Google can lag a few days behind and that these errors will remain for quite a bit of time even when you fix the problem and the sitemap has been read, accepted, and used to index your site. One other point, since your site is so small, do not expect Google to actually use the site map instead preferring to spider the site.

Comment: Hi closetnoc. As I mentioned in @Helius 's post I installed everything from the beginning and set everything to www.buraktas.com (in google analytics and webmaster tool). The annoying thing is my friend also used the same steps and he is indexed instanly on google. Well, I will install my site map again.Hope it will work

Comment: I understand. I cannot swear to it, but it may be that Google is expecting www.buraktas.com in the site map. You can hand edit these files just to know. As well, Google may be reading your files okay now and you may never know this. Google lags behind a few days and the error messages will not go away for a while. I went through something like this and it was kinda confusing until I realized what was going on.

Comment: I checked your site prior to adding my answer. It was okay. The message from Google has nothing to do with DNS and getting to your site. I has everything to do with what Google is reading in your sitemap.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I guess waiting a couple of days is best thing to do.

Comment: Yeah. I hear ya! And you are right. You may need to check that Google is not expecting the www. It may take days to know if what you have now works and then another few days to know if www is needed by trying it. Just keep this in mind. Either way, right now, it not as important that the sitemap is working correctly. It will become important as your site grows. For now, it can error and not cause you any harm.

Comment: Anytime. I am here at odd times when most people are out having a life. I like doing this. I have been helping people with their websites for well over a decade simply because it is fun for me. I am weird that way. ;-)

Comment: haha. then see you in next few days :D

Answer (score 1):

Google can sometimes take a while to update their UI, so it may take a while for what you're seeing to change. Did you recently point DNS records? If so, it can take up to 24 hours to propagate.

A dig shows ---

```
H3LIUS:~ connarpierce$ dig buraktas.com

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;buraktas.com.          IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
buraktas.com.       14400   IN  A   198.46.82.210

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
buraktas.com.       43199   IN  NS  ns1.webhostinghub.com.
buraktas.com.       43199   IN  NS  ns2.webhostinghub.com.
```

As long as that IP is the server it's supposed to point to, you should be fine in a few hours. Also, check for a robots.txt. I used to work for InMotion Hosting which actually owns WebHosting Hub and they had default robots.txt files that came with your site. This file can block bots.

Comment: Actually, I removed and installed wordpress again with http://www protocol, the latter was http://. Also I was having issues about verifying my domain through google analytics. Now it verified direclty by google analytics. So I have removed the TXT record from my DNS properties. The thing is I have adjust many many times about DNS, TXT records, verifying installing and unistalling google analytics. Hope everything should be ok. I find robots.txt file but could not understand anything about the content. Should I share it ?